# rails mongoid query multiple fields with same value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, mongoid

I have 3 fields with `type: Time`.

```
field :last_updated, type: Time
field :last_event, type: Time
field :last_status, type: Time
```

How can I make a query - that will give me all records that all those fields are less than 30 minutes ago?

I don't want to write the following query -

```
Model.where(:last_status.lt => 30.minutes.ago,:last_event.lt => 30.minutes.ago,:last_updated.lt => 30.minutes.ago).all
```

I would like to do something like:

```
def updated_date
  timestamps = [self.last_status,self.last_event,self.last_updated]
  timestamps.reject(&:nil?).max
end
Model.where(updated_date.lt => 30.minutes.ago).all
```

But it's not working...

I don't want to maintain more field that will be updated with the most updated field each time one of those fields is updated...

Any ideas?

Comment: what's the problem with the method `updated_date`.. It is not working ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is the working code:

```
def updated_date
  timestamps = [ :last_status, :last_event, :last_updated ]
  timestamps.reject { |sym| self.public_send(sym).nil? }
            .max { |sym| self.public_send(sym) }
end

Model.where(:updated_date.lt => 30.minutes.ago).all
```

Anoter way to write the `updated_date` method which will save double *method calls*.

```
def updated_date
  timestamps = { 
                 last_status: self.last_status,
                 last_event: self.last_event,
                 last_updated: self.last_updated
               }
  timestamps.reject { |_, v| v.nil? }.max_by(&:last).first
end
Model.where(:updated_date.lt => 30.minutes.ago).all
```

Comment: Can you explain? what is public_send?

Comment: I'm getting `undefined local variable or method updated_date for main:Object`

Comment: B.T.W - do you know why in the first option `Model.first.updated_date` isn't working while in the second one it is working?

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method to_datetime for 0:Fixnum
`

Comment: @user2503775 No idea.. If it works then please accept it.. And let me know which version worked.. I'll delete the other answer//

Comment: Sure I'll accept it. But pls leave both of them. The second code works better. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, it was my mistake. I see now it's not working well. `Model.where(:updated_date.lt => 30.minutes.ago).count` gives `. => 0` while `Model.where(:last_status.lt => 30.minutes.ago).count` gives `. => 3`. Any idea?